# close down application - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a button that will close my app.

I am using `exit(0);` but I dont like the way it closes my app, its like when an app crashes and the app closes kinda close. I am looking for away to terminate when the user pushes this button. Any suggestions?

Thanks

I have tried the following:

```
[[NSThread mainThread] exit];
```

but got this error:

```
No visible @interface for 'NSThread' declares the selector 'exit'
```

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Answer (score 2):

The is no proper way to do that. You should use `exit(0);` to go from application. But for increasing of the user experience just add some few lines :

```
        //home button press programmatically
        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];

        //wait 2 seconds while app is going background
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

        //exit app when app is in background
        exit(0);
```

Comment: This kind of works, but it does not close the app in the background

Comment: when I goto see what apps are in the background and its still there

Comment: One of the best solution i found. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The only approved method to exit an app it to set the (Apple documented) exits-on-suspend app plist key, and then have the app send a URL to launch another app (such as Safari).  iOS will then cleanly terminate your app instead of backgrounding it.

Comment: Didn't know this mechanism existed. Could you please provide a link of the related documentation

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: That's the ''Application does not run in background" key. Wouldn't using that mean we are never able to run our app in background even when force closing mechanism was required in one use case?